# Federated learning weighted aggregation

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, federated-learning

I would like to add different weights to clients in Federated learning, so in the aggregation stage, each client has a different impact on the global model.

For example:

```
Client_1 has 2X impact
Client_2 has X impact
```

I am looking for suggestions to implement this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You need to do it in the aggregation part of your local models. there you can scale each local client's model and aggregate them accordingly. ex: `w_golb = (2*w_loc_01 + w_loc_02)/3` what you need to keep in mind is, that you need to multiply layer by layer